# Query the user name of the double letter

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to find usernames with reduplicated words in my database

Below is my SQL statement：

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY `name` regexp 'a{2}|b{2}|c{2}|d{2}|e{2}|f{2}|g{2}|h{2}|i{2}|j{2}|k{2}|l{2}|m{2}|n{2}|o{2}|p{2}|q{2}|r{2}|s{2}|t{2}|u{2}|v{2}|w{2}|x{2}|y{2}|z{2}'
```

I guess there should be an easier way, but I don't know how to do it.

I also want to find usernames like 'ABAA' or 'AABA', but I won't write this SQL or say this regex

Comment: If by any chance you can upgrade your MySQL database to MariaDB, a drop-in replacement for MySQL, you can solve the problem with a regex using a backreference.

Comment: i found the answer, @blhsing you are right.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (The regex syntax has changed.)

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL's regex engine does not support backreferences, your approach is reasonable.  To simplify your query, you could maintain a table of double letters:

```
table: letters (val)
aa
bb
...
zz
```

Now your query can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM letters l
    WHERS INSTR(u.name, l.val) > 0
);
```

Comment: This is a good way, but I want the query to be case sensitive,but `INSTR` is case insensitive. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Is there any way to look up usernames like 'ABAA'or 'AABA'.

Comment: `Thanks anyway for your help` ... just lowercase the username before comparing it against the lookup table.

Comment: @QAQ *INSTR is case insensitive* ??? Who tells this to you? Study "collation" term. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30b2f585e28ef910e1b67dae2e13498d

Comment: I'm sorry for not fully describing my problem, usernames with case combinations like 'Aa' or 'Bb' are not what I'm looking for,`LOWER` gives wrong query results

Comment: Then 1) use a case sensitive collation for your table and the table of letters and 2) insert both `aa` and `AA` into the letters table.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for making me learn something new

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
create table users(name varchar(100));
insert into users (name) values
       ("abaa"),
       ("bba"),
       ("abc"),
       ("aCCa");

SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) REGEXP 'aa|bb|cc|dd|ee|ff|gg|hh|ii|jj|kk|ll|mm|nn|oo|pp|qq|rr|ss|tt|uu|vv|ww|xx|yy|zz';
```

Prints:

```
abaa
bba
aCCa
```

Comment: What happened to x y and z?  Also, this is not much more maintainable than the OP's current code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sharp eye. Forgot the xyz. It saves 52 characters and therefor somewhat easier on the eye and maintain. Either way, I did vote for your solution as a smoother alternative.

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the answer,I upgraded my MySQL database to MariaDB.

this is my sql statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `name` REGEXP '([a-z])\\1'
```

This is the sql statement to query like 'aaba':

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `name` REGEXP '([a-z])\\1((?!\\1)[a-z])\\1'
```

Note: Because MariaDB uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, "\n" to represent the newline character), you must double any "" that you use in your REGEXP strings.

Comment: [Documentation link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pcre/#absolute-and-relative-numeric-backreferences)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0

```
WHERE name REGEXP '([a-z])\\1'
```

Let the collation take care of ignore case.